# Returning object vs. reference in default constructor signature

Tags: c++, reference, constructor, default

Essentially, what's the difference between:

```
const Date& default_date()
{
    static Date dd(2001,Date::Jan,1);
    return dd;
}
```

and

```
const Date default_date()
{
    static Date dd(2001,Date::Jan,1);
    return dd;
}
```

Does the function signature really matter? I don't think of Date& as a type like *Date, so I'm not sure what difference this makes. Does it just prevent a copy from being made on the return? But then wouldn't you return &dd?

Comment: Sounds like this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c

Comment: const or not, i would never use the & operator to return anything from inside a ?function? If you something outside allocate it otherwise somebody in a large code base will eventually remove the const and your application ends up with terrible segvaults

Comment: Question heading is bit confusing, Returning object vs. reference in **default constructor signature**, IMO **bold** part should removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first function returns a const reference to the static object, so you can do this:

```
const Date& d = default_date(); // d is a reference to the original
```

or

```
Date d = default_date(); // d is a copy of the original, 
                         // provided there is a copy constructor
```

The second one makes a copy of the `static Date` object, so you can only get a copy

```
Date d = default_date(); // d is a copy of the original
```

Returning `&dd` would return the address of the static object, which could then be assigned to a pointer to `Date`. The syntax for the return statement is the same for return by reference or return by value. The semantics depend on the return type of the function.

Note that in C++, functions such as `default_date` are not referred to as constructors.

Comment: In the former, i think you're missing an '=' sign, as that doesn't compile as-is. In the latter, there is no provisional condition of a copy constructor, as without one (default or otherwise) the code will not compile either. the rest I'm totally behind (and up-voted).

Comment: @CraigNelson thanks, someone else fixed the mistake. I haven't added the explicit condition of a copy constructor for the latter example because the function itself wouldn't compile without it.